# USB vendor specific class with Bulk transfer in LPC1769 Microcontroller

Tags: c, usb, microcontroller, nxp-microcontroller

I am trying to achieve USB vendor specific class with Bulk transfer in LPC1769 Microcontroller.
I got an USB Biometric module, extracted it's device information. Accordingly I have configured the following descriptor.

```
const uint8_t USB_DeviceDescriptor[]={};
const uint8_t USB_ConfigDescriptor[]={};
const uint8_t USB_StringDescriptor[]={};
```

Now my USB Biometric device and my LPC1769 device has similar type of device information 
(I have seen it from my Ubuntu PC using this command "lsusb -v")
But, when I am plugging it to windows it should come to USB class (Trident symbol list) in device manager. USB Bio-metric device is listing under "Universal Serial Bus controller".

I am not able to find any Any document, flowchart 
Could anyone please guide me how to established communication in vendor specific class.

USB biometric device information

```
Bus 003 Device 023: ID 16d1:0407  
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x16d1 
  idProduct          0x0407 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              300mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

My LPC1769 USB device Information

```
Bus 003 Device 018: ID 1fc9:2002 NXP Semiconductors 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1fc9 NXP Semiconductors
  idProduct          0x2002 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 1 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              3 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
>     bmAttributes            2
>       Transfer Type            Bulk
>       Synch Type               None
>       Usage Type               Data
>     wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
> ```

The LPC1769 only supports USB full speed, thus Bulk EPs have a `wMaxPacketSize` of 64 Bytes max. Only high speed devices support 512 byte Bulk EPs.

To operate "vendor specific" class USB devices, you use either a specific kernel driver or [LibUSB](http://libusb.info/)/WinUSB as driver together with a user mode application.

Comment: Thank you very much. After changing the VID/PID similar to that USB device, I am getting my device in the "Universal Serial Bus" List. I forgot that previously I have install driver for that.
I am trying LibUSB as you suggested.
Could you please tell me how can I send the data and receive the data to USB device from PC end?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is no driver installed for particular USB device (VID and PID), it will shows "?Other devices" 
in the device manager. But, for my case it was listing under "Communication Devices Class" although I have 
change my USB class protocol to "Vendor Specific Class". Why? The driver instance is trying to map with the 
same VID and PID.  I have changed my identical to that of USB Bio-metric device. It shows in the "Universal 
Serial Bus Controller listing".

Now, you can integrate the same with your Android Tab with "Android Studio Platform" there is an API called "UsbManager"
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html

Thanks for your participation.